# WPF multiple combobox communication

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am working on WPF application. One of the window contains 6 combo-boxes.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ScenarioIDcb" Margin="0,5,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="ScenarioIDcb_SelectionChanged"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="ScenarioNamecb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="ScenarioDescriptioncb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="StepIDcb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="StepNamecb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="StepDescriptioncb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="Expectedresultcb" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

They are all bound to one observable collection of string (ExcelColumnames ).

```
private void SetCBDataContext()
{
    if (this.ExcelColumnames != null && this.ExcelColumnames.Count > 0)
    {
        ScenarioIDcb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        ScenarioNamecb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        ScenarioDescriptioncb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        StepIDcb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        StepNamecb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        StepDescriptioncb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
        Expectedresultcb.DataContext = this.ExcelColumnames;
    }          
}
```

What I want achieve is, if user selection value in one of the combo-box, it shouldn't appear into other combo-boxes. If user select some other value in the same combo-box the previously selected value should appear in the other combo-boxes for selection. Please guide me.

Thanks Priyank

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is move to a GridView ListView and one column is the name and shared by all.  Then have a boolean value for each of the 7 to indicate if the value is selected.  Put a filter on each the 7 to eliminate the value if it is selected by any of the other 6.  ExcelColumnames will need to be an ObservableCollection.   For the filtering see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx.   You might get away with one filter and pass it the ID so it knows to look at all the others.

Another approach is one List for all the ExcelColumnanames that has 7 bool properties.  Then create 7 ObservableCollections from the List and use Linq to filter in the .where.   In this case the master is definitely a List and not an ObservableCollection as linking an ObservableCollection to a List is pretty straight forward (just pass the List in the constructor) but linking an ObservableCollection to and ObservableCollection is not.   I am pretty sure you can pass a List with Linq in the constructor but not positive.